# log4j2 ReusableMessageFactory.getParameterized() create too many threadLocal, 125MB

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, thread-local

In my project, using `ReusableMessageFactory` create log message, which call

```java
private static ThreadLocal<ReusableParameterizedMessage> threadLocalParameterized = new ThreadLocal<>();
private static ReusableParameterizedMessage getParameterized() {
    ReusableParameterizedMessage result = threadLocalParameterized.get();
    if (result == null) {
        result = new ReusableParameterizedMessage();
        threadLocalParameterized.set(result);
    }
    return result.reserved ? new ReusableParameterizedMessage().reserve() : result.reserve();
}

public static void release(final Message message) { // LOG4J2-1583
    if (message instanceof Clearable) {
        ((Clearable) message).clear();
    }
}
```

In the last line, `result.reserved ? new ReusableParameterizedMessage().reserve() : result.reserve();`, create too many `ReusableParameterizedMessage` which then create threadLocal and not call `threadLocal.remove()`, too may threadLocal exist.

In my memory dump,  one tomcat thread have 155857 threadLocal entry where almost created by `ReusableParameterizedMessage.buffer`, occupy `125MB`.

Two many threadLocal lead to frequently threadLoalMap hash conflict, `ThreadLocalMap.getEntryAfterMiss()` consuming excessive CPU time.

Usually `logger.info()` will call `ReusableMessageFactory.release()` set `reserved` to false,  why create so many `ReusableParameterizedMessage` and `buffer`.

Below is Eclipse Memory Analyzer  screen.

[image: very much threadLocal occupy large memory]

Is this normal? if not, how fix this?

Comment: On Tomcat the [`Constants.ENABLE_THREADLOCALS`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Constants.html#ENABLE_THREADLOCALS) kill switch is disabled. Can you explain how you use `ReusableMessageFactory` in your code? By the properties of `ThreadLocal`, there is only one entry per thread. Do you use thousands of threads or virtual threads?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  tks.  I find we did indeed misuse the `ReusableMessageFactory` .  I will provide a detailed description of how we misused it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After read log4j code,  We did indeed misuse the `ReusableMessageFactory`, our code :

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyLogger {

    private static final MessageFactory2 MESSAGE_FACTORY = new ReusableMessageFactory();
    private Logger logger;

    public static MyLogger getLogger(String name) {
        return new MyLogger(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(name));
    }

    public void info(String title, String format, Map<String, String> attrs, Object... arguments) {
        String str = MESSAGE_FACTORY.newMessage(format, arguments).getFormattedMessage();
        // append title, tags or trace tags...
        String message = appendTitleTag(str);
        logger.debug(message);
    }
    .....
}
```

`ReusableMessageFactory.newMessage()` then need call `ReusableMessageFactory.release()` to set `reserved` to false after log, bus we did not call.

That's why wo have so many threadLocals.

Other:

1. `ReusableParameterizedMessage.buffer` remove static modifier, [commit link](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/ae87a679f4a04a2b1f3458fe62e469ae806a7eb9)